# Importing library 'Browser' failed: ModuleNotFoundError in .robot file using RobotFramwework

Tags: browser, robotframework

1. newly created robocorp robotframework poetry template.
2. pyproject.toml file and use a Virtual Environment.
3. run command to check project python interpreter

   1. c#poetry env info --path
   2. C:\Users\xxxx\RobocorpPoetry.ven

   sample .robot file:

   *** Settings ***

   Documentation    this file contains automate test cases using browser library.

   Library    Browser

   *** Variables *** ${URL}        https://robotframework.org

   *** Test Cases ***

   TC1: Launch application

   ```
             Open browser    ${URL}    chromium Log    test done!
   ```

   pyproject.toml refers below [tool.poetry.dependencies] python = "^3.11" robotframework = "^6.1" robotframework-browser = "*"

   execute .robot test show import of Browser library not found.

   can someone help what could be the issue here.